# Django , Use Viewsets inside views.py

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I'm using a `ViewSet` to implement restful API.

For a similar operation in `views.py`, I want to use those API methods.

How can I use API calls inside my `views.py`?

Here is `ViewSet` class with one `GET` method:

```
class ProductViewSet(ViewSet):

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
    def get_price_with_code(self, request):
        some operations ...
```

Here is `views.py` and I want to use `get_price_with_code` in `index` method:

```
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "showProduct.html", {})
    else:
        code = request.POST['pr_code']
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        # use get_price_with_code method to get results
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
  if request.method == "GET":
    return render(request, "showProduct.html", {})
  else:
    code = request.POST['pr_code']
    phone = request.POST['phone']
    product_object = ProductViewSet()
    price = product_object.get_price_with_code(request)
    # use get_price_with_code method to get results
```

Tried it on, one of my projects :

```
from ticket.models import Organisation
from ticket.serializers import OrganisationModelSerializer
from pydbug.views import CreatedUpdatedViewSetMixin

class OrganisationModelViewSet(CreatedUpdatedViewSetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""

"""
  queryset = Organisation.objects.all()
  serializer_class = OrganisationModelSerializer

  def get_queryset(self):
      return Organisation.objects.all()
```

```
def test():
  o = OrganisationModelViewSet()
  print(o.get_queryset())
test()
```

## Prints :

`<QuerySet [<Organisation: poiytrewqwertiop[>, <Organisation: PSegs>, <Organisation: DGR>]>`

Viewset is a class and works like a python class.